# Calculate sum from three tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 3 mysql tables:

```
Client_courses
Client_courses_id Client_id Course_id
1                    1          2
2                    1          3
3                    2          1

Client
Client_id Name
1         Tom
2         John

Courses
Course_id Name         Price
1         Microsofr    100
2         Programming  250
3         Leadership   300
```

I need to calculate how much every client spent money on courses. For example: Tom spent 550 (250+300), John spent 100. And I am confused how to do it.

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag accordingly.

Comment: You need to join your tables togther, do you know how to do a join?

Comment: No, I need that to project, which Im currently working on. I'am trying to do this for hours, but it still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(c.Price), cl.Name
FROM Client cl
INNER JOIN Client_courses clc ON cl.Client_id=clc.Client_id
INNER JOIN Courses cs ON clc.Course_id=cs.Course_id
GROUP BY cl.Name
```